# Is the decision surface for a Probit model linear?

Tags: probit, multinomial-logit

For example, if we threshold our classification on $0.5$, is the decision surface necessarily linear?  It is linear for Multinomial Logit models, but it's not obvious to me that it is for Probit models.

Comment: The decision surface would have a huge discontinuity if you set any threshold, in what sense do you say it is linear?  Do you mean the decision *boundary*?

Comment: Is the model linear in the variables or not?

Comment: I mean the surface, in feature space, upon which the output of the model is $0.5$... Is that what you mean by decision boundary?

Comment: @whuber, Do you mean, have I transformed the variables, like adding a variable_1 squared column before fitting?  If that is what you mean, then I mean linear in the post-transformation feature space.

Comment: Then doesn't that answer your question?

Comment: @whuber mind>>blown